# Read Big File (over 60GB) and Write new File

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata, file-processing

There is one file that is 60GB in size and 200,000,000 rows . The payload of the file is shown below.

source.txt

```
0.0 4.6 6.3 3.8 5.0 0.0 -3.8 -5.9 1.5 14.2 0.0 1.0 6.9 5.8 6.1 0.0 5.4 -7.1 0.9 6.8 0.0 -1.8 2.6 0.0 -11.5 -0.0 
0.0 13.4 -1.8 5.2 2.4 0.0 -7.1 -12.5 -2.8 11.8 0.0 2.0 5.5 3.5 8.2 0.0 9.2 -18.2 -3.4 1.7 0.0 -16.1 3.2 0.0 9.7 -0.1 
0.0 12.2 -2.0 7.2 0.1 0.0 -9.1 -11.8 -2.5 8.8 0.0 1.1 4.6 3.8 8.0 0.0 8.3 -18.5 -5.0 0.6 0.0 -14.3 2.8 0.0 10.6 -0.0 
0.0 10.6 -0.6 8.3 -2.2 0.0 -9.4 -8.4 -1.5 5.3 0.0 1.9 3.5 3.6 7.1 0.0 7.6 -16.5 -5.7 0.6 0.0 -9.5 1.9 0.0 7.8 0.0
```

I want to read the files in order and make a new file including the sequence number. The payload of the file to be created is as follows.

destination.txt

```
 1: 0.0 4.6 6.3 3.8 5.0 0.0 -3.8 -5.9 1.5 14.2 0.0 1.0 6.9 5.8 6.1 0.0 5.4 -7.1 0.9 6.8 0.0 -1.8 2.6 0.0 -11.5 -0.0 
 2: 0.0 13.4 -1.8 5.2 2.4 0.0 -7.1 -12.5 -2.8 11.8 0.0 2.0 5.5 3.5 8.2 0.0 9.2 -18.2 -3.4 1.7 0.0 -16.1 3.2 0.0 9.7 -0.1 
 3: 0.0 12.2 -2.0 7.2 0.1 0.0 -9.1 -11.8 -2.5 8.8 0.0 1.1 4.6 3.8 8.0 0.0 8.3 -18.5 -5.0 0.6 0.0 -14.3 2.8 0.0 10.6 -0.0 
 4: 0.0 10.6 -0.6 8.3 -2.2 0.0 -9.4 -8.4 -1.5 5.3 0.0 1.9 3.5 3.6 7.1 0.0 7.6 -16.5 -5.7 0.6 0.0 -9.5 1.9 0.0 7.8 0.0
```

I can use Java to do the following

```
    String filePath = "/filepath";

    Path path = Paths.get(filePath+"/source.txt");

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = Files.newBufferedReader(path);

    Stream<String> lines = bufferedReader.lines();
    AtomicLong seq = new AtomicLong(0);

    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(filePath+"/dest.txt"));

    lines.forEach(txt -> {
        try {
            bufferedWriter.append(seq.addAndGet(1) + ":" + txt);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

but I'm wondering if it's possible using a distributed universal framework like Spark or Storm or Hadoop. I think big data frameworks make it faster

Comment: You would need to iterate every line, in order, and keep track of that counter. There's no way to distribute a sequential count without knowing how many lines you're splitting the file into. Even then, you don't need a big data framework since you could use multithreading

Comment: cricket_007 appreciate your answer

Comment: It's just a comment... Plus, if you did store that file in HDFS, it would be split into multiple smaller files behind the scenes, so once again, you'd have to know what original line number each part started at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something which may be helpful in Spark.

1. Create an RDD from the CSV file
2. Use a combination of zipWithIndex, sortBy, map

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/26081548/290036 for a zipWithIndex example

Comment: Why sortBy? And what is being mapped? Could you share an example?